# Find synonyms and antonyms set of given adjective using wordnet in java

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

i am working on  nlp project in java, i want to get Synonyms and Antonyms set of given adjective using wordnet. So far i have done this, but i am not getting the desired output which is just list of synonyms and antonym set.

```
    net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.Dictionary dict;
    File file = new File("properties.xml");
    JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream(file));
    dict = net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.Dictionary.getInstance();

    IndexWord indexWord = dict.getIndexWord(POS.ADJECTIVE, "bad");

    Synset[] senses = indexWord.getSenses();


    for(int i=0;i<senses.length;i++){
        Synset set= senses[i];
        Word[] words=set.getWords();
        for(int k=0;k<words.length;k++){
            System.out.println(i+","+k+":"+words[k].getLemma());
        }

    }
```

Output

INFO: Installing dictionary net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary@70177ecd

good ,
full ,
good ,
good ,
estimable ,
good ,
honorable ,
respectable ,
beneficial ,
good ,
good ,
good ,
just ,
upright ,
adept ,
expert ,
good ,
practiced ,
proficient ,
skillful ,
skilful ,
good ,
dear ,
good ,
near ,
dependable ,
good ,
safe ,
secure ,
good ,
right ,
ripe ,
good ,
well(p) ,
effective ,
good ,
in_effect(p) ,
in_force(p) ,
good ,
good ,
serious ,
good ,
sound ,
good ,
salutary ,
good ,
honest ,
good ,
unspoiled ,
unspoilt ,
good ,

Answer (score 0):

you need to filter your answer,

```js
Synset syn;
       String word = null;
       ArrayList syns = new ArrayList<>();
         for(int i=0;i<sensesVerbe.length;i++){
            // syn=sensesVerbe[i];          
            //System.out.println(sensesVerbe[i]); 
           
            String v= sensesVerbe[i].toString();
            //String v= sensesVerbe[i].toString();
            if(v.contains("Words:")){
                          //System.out.println("yeeh");
                          //System.out.println("Index of NN = "+ line.indexOf("N "));
                          int chaine = v.indexOf("Words:");
                          //System.out.println("index Words: ="+ chaine+"");
                          
                          int chaine1 = v.indexOf("--");
                          //System.out.println("index -- ="+ chaine1+"");
                          
                          word = v.substring(chaine+6, chaine1);
                          //System.out.println("the sub of line where index is ("+ chaine +","+ chaine1 +") is :" + word);
                         
                          //System.out.println(word); 
                          String mots[] =word.split(",");
                          //System.out.println("mots séparés :"); 
                          for (int j = 0; j < mots.length; j++) {
                                mots[j]=mots[j].replaceAll(" ", "");
                                //System.out.println(mots[j]);
                                if(!syns.contains(mots[j].toLowerCase())){
                                   syns.add(mots[j].toLowerCase());
                                }
                            }                                                    
               }
         }
```